# Binary probabilty problem

Tags: probability

I'm tinkering with some probability exercises and I think I understand the second question but I'm stuck on the 1st question.

What is the probability that a 12 zeros and ones have exactly five ones but begins and ends in zero?

What is the probability that 12 zeros and ones have at least eight ones but begins and ends in zero?

Since the array of numbers begins and ends in zero, I believe I have 10 spaces to work with so I tried this...

$$ \frac{10!}{8!(10-8)!} \Rightarrow \frac{10!}{8!(8-2)!} \Rightarrow \frac{10*9}{2} \Rightarrow \frac{90}{2} \Rightarrow 45 .$$

Is this correct?

Comment: This is not clear.  In the first one ,are you asking "given a binary string of length $12$, what is the probability that the first and last digits are $0$ and there are exactly $5$ ones?"?   The answer to that is clearly not "$45$".

Comment: Also, what does $\frac {10!}{8!(10-8)!}\implies \frac {10!}{8!(8-2)!}$ mean?

Comment: Its a binary string of 12 zeros and ones.  Because the string begins and ends with zero, I thought I wouldnt count those so I worked with 10.  And the => were pointing to my next step in working out the math.  I didnt know how else to say it.

Comment: But what you wrote makes no sense.  Are you saying those fractions are equal?  But they clearly are not.  And, of course, $45$ can't be a probability.

Comment: Regardless, It looks like you are trying to count the number of good strings. That's a sensible first step.  If you had that value, then you could divide by the total number of strings to get the probability.  Hint: to count the good strings (in the first question)  note that a good string is entirely determined by the location of the $5$ ones.

Comment: To get the location of the 5 strings do I need to use a binary coeficient?

Comment: Yes.  There are $10$ available places, $5$ of which must be selected.  But use words carefully.  It's not "$5$  strings" you are counting.  You are counting the possible configurations of a string.

Comment: so n=10 and k=5 ...therefore (10,5)...sorry not sure how to type that on a website

Comment: But you still have to divide by the total number of strings to get a probability.

Comment: I did 10 C 5 = (10,5) = 252/12?

Comment: Do you believe that there are only $12$ binary strings of length $12$?  Do you believe that $\frac {252}{12}$ is a possible probability?  Please think about your work.  Don't guess blindly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can forget the first and last zero. The problems are

> Given $10$ binary digits, what is the probability that *exactly* $5$ of them are ones?

And

> Given $10$ binary digits, what is the probability that *at least* $8$ of them are ones?

**Assuming that the zeros and ones are equally likely,** you can use the binomial distribution to deal with both of these questions. Let $X\sim \operatorname{Binom}(10,1/2)$ be random variable denoting the number of ones in the string. We can compute simply
$$\Pr(X=5)={}_{10}\mathrm{C}_5 \cdot (1/2)^5(1-1/2)^{10-5}=\frac{45}{2^{10}}\approx 0.0439$$
For the other part,
$$\Pr(X\geq 8)=\sum_{k=8}^{10} {}_{10}\mathrm{C}_k\cdot(1/2)^k(1-1/2)^{10-k}=\frac{7}{128}\approx 0.0547$$

Comment: I suspect the problem is badly worded: the 'but begins' may or may not be a conditional statement

Comment: Good point, @Snoop.